# WP Rest API Custom endpoint - JSON returns NULL

Tags: php, json, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to slim down the JSON returned when using the Rest API. I am able to get it to work using the "_embed" parameter in the query, but it returns a HUGE amount of data I don't need. So, per WP best practices I want to set up a custom end point and in it's callback call a function to output the three items I need. Seems simple, however it returns NULL for all nodes when I try. In my functions.php file I have:

```
function get_all_posts( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    return [
        'id'        => $data->data['id'],
        'title'     => $data->data['title']['rendered'],
        'link'      => $data->data['link'],
        'date'      => $data->data['date'], //not correct
        //similar calls to get thumbnail image and category
    ];
}
```

Then the route and call back for the custom endpoint

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'mydata/v1', '/all', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_all_posts',
    ) );
} );
```

when I use the url - https://somedomain.com/blog/wp-json/mydata/v1/all I get the following on page:

```
{
    "id": null,
    "title": null,
    "link": null
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass field arguments to the API
Like so:

```
[url]/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?fields=id,name
```

Note this is example is /tags, you can use /categories etc, and still specify the fields. 
I recommend installing the JSONView chrome plugin so that the dump of your JSON is readable when you test the endpoint .